# How to create custom checks in tfsec

Tags: terraform, tfsec

I have the following policy that I wish to implement in my IaC code scan using tfsec:

`Custom Check: GCP Firewall rule allows all traffic on Telnet port (23)`

The below is my custom check in .json format:

```json
{
  "checks": 
    [
      {
        "code": "CUS003",
        "description": "Custom Check: GCP Firewall rule allows all traffic on Telnet port (23)",
        "requiredTypes": 
          [
            "resource"
          ],
          "requiredLabels": 
          [
            "google_compute_firewall"
          ],
          "severity": "WARNING",
          "matchSpec": 
          {
            "name": "CUS003_matchSpec_name",
            "action": "and",
            "predicateMatchSpec": 
            [
                  {
                    "name": "source_ranges",
                    "action": "contains",
                    "value": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ports",
                    "action": "contains",
                    "value": "23"
                }
            ]
          },
        "errorMessage": "[WARNING] GCP Firewall rule allows all traffic on Telnet port (23)",
        "relatedLinks": 
          [
            "https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_firewall"
          ]
      }
    ]  
}
```

I have tried using "not", "notContains", "equals", a combination of "subMatch" and/or "predicateMatchSpec" but nothing worked.

To test it out I have purposefully created firewall rules that should fail and others that should pass the checks. When I get check failures, it's for all rules, not just a few ones. Similarly when I get check passes, it's for all rules, not just a few ones.

Docs that might be useful: [tfsec custom checks](https://tfsec.dev/docs/custom_checks/)

Any help is appreciated. Unfortunately "tfsec" isn't a tag so I am hoping it's a terraform issue that I am facing.

Comment: Hey - I'll take a look at this, might be a bug. We do take issues (https://github.com/tfsec/tfsec/issues), I only found this by fluke when someone sent it to me (I'm one of the core devs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think now looking at it formatted its clear that `source_ranges` is a child of the `google_compute_firewall` resource. The `ports` attribute is a child of the `allow`. Your check is assuming that `ports` is a sibling of `source_ranges`.

I think this check is achievable with the following - it does a predicate check that there is source_range as required AND there is a block called allow, with an attribute ports containing 23

```json
{
  "checks": [
    {
      "code": "CUS003",
      "description": "Custom Check: GCP Firewall rule allows all traffic on Telnet port (23)",
      "requiredTypes": [
        "resource"
      ],
      "requiredLabels": [
        "google_compute_firewall"
      ],
      "severity": "WARNING",
      "matchSpec": {
        "action": "and",
        "predicateMatchSpec": [
          {
            "name": "source_ranges",
            "action": "contains",
            "value": "0.0.0.0/0"
          },
          {
            "name": "allow",
            "action": "isPresent",
            "subMatch": {
              "name": "ports",
              "action": "contains",
              "value": "23",
              "ignoreUndefined": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "errorMessage": "[WARNING] GCP Firewall rule allows all traffic on Telnet port (23)",
      "relatedLinks": [
        "https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_firewall"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tested it against the following body

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
  name    = "test-firewall"
  network = google_compute_network.default.name

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["23", "8080", "1000-2000"]
  }
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  source_tags = ["web"]
}

resource "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "test-network"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Based on the above example, slightly modified for an inverse effect, it worked as I had hoped for!